# Porque no me ejecuta la funcion validarCorreo?

Tags: javascript

estoy practicando javascript con los formularios, lo que trato de hacer es que cuando el usuario no escriba nada en los inputs se debe de mostrar un mensaje mediante listas, para ello cree 2 funciones una para el nombre y otra para el correo y para que se ejecuten simultaneamente puse las 2 en una misma funcion cuando el input del nombre esta vacio me muestra el mensaje perfectamente pero el input del correo no me lo muestra estando este vacio tambien, no entiendo por que siendo estas 2 funciones casi el mismo codigo

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario" name="formulario">
        <div class="input-formulario">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo">

            <div class="sexo">
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="hombre" value="hombre">
            <label for="hombre" class="label-radio hombre">Hombre</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="mujer" value="hombre">
            <label for="mujer" class="label-radio mujer">Mujer</label>
            </div>

            <div class="terminos">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos">
            <label for="terminos">Acepto Terminos y Condiciones</label>
            </div>
            <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Registrarse">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="formulario.js"></script>
```

//(function(){

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario"),

    nombre = formulario.nombre,

    correo = formulario.correo,

    sexo = formulario.sexo,

    terminos = formulario.terminos,

    error = document.getElementById ("error");

function validarNombre(e){
    if(nombre.value == "" || nombre.value == null){
        error.style.display = "block";
        error.innerHTML += "<li>por favor rellena el nombre</li>";
        console.log ("por favor rellena el nombre");

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        error.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function validarCorreo(e){
    if(correo.value == "" || correo.value == null){
        error.style.display = "block";
        error.innerHTML += "<li>por favor rellena el correo</li>";
        console.log ("por favor rellena el correo");

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        error.style.display = "none";
    }
}

//function validarSexo(e){}

//function validarTerminos(e){}

function validarFormulario(e){
    validarNombre(e);
    validarCorreo(e);
    //validarSexo(e);
    //validarTerminos(e);
}
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validarNombre);
```

//}())

Comment: La plataforma *SO en español*, soporta la creación de *snippets*, por favor  considera agregar aquí todo el código necesario

Answer (score 0):

En el listener debes poner:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validarFormulario);
```

En ves de:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validarNombre);
```